# Precautions before using a pre-sale address?

Tags: presale

After the Ethereum pre-sale I've been pretty much out of the loop. Now I would like to start using my ETH but I'm not sure if it's that straightforward. I would not like to mess up and lose ETH because of my stupidity or carelessness.

1. Do I have to explicitly split my ETH from ETC because of the DAO hard fork? What happens if I don't do that?
2. Is there something else that needs to be taken into account before making transactions from a pre-sale address?